# Android TableLayout make all buttons same size

Tags: android

I'm making a custom dialer and want to have all the buttons be the same size but because some of the text is longer than others (e.g. the "7" button has "PQRS" under it) it stretches out some columns.  Here is what I'm doing currently, what am I doing wrong?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_one" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_two" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_three" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_four" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_five" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_six" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_seven" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_eight" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_nine" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_star" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_zero" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/dialer_pound" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :
And if you don't want to fill your whole screen then remove the `weightSum` of the main `TableLayout` and respective `layout_weight` in TableRows

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:text="dialer_one"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:text="dialer_two"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:text="dialer_three"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="dialer_four"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="dialer_five"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="dialer_six"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="dialer_seven"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="dialer_eight"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="dialer_nine"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="dialer_star"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="dialer_zero"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="dialer_pound"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This should work

Comment: This still makes the columns uneven width.

Comment: Can you post the picture of layout you are getting by adding my code.

Answer (score 1):

use linear layout instead of table layout and set weight=1 for all buttons. it will give you positive result what you want..

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TableRow
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_one" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_two" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_three" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_four" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_five" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_six" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_seven" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_eight" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_nine" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_star" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_zero" />
    <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="dialer_pound" />
</TableRow>
```

I think this is what you want..

Answer (score 0):

**Use WeightSum and Weight** in order to have all buttons of equal width like this,

```
 <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:text="@string/dialer_one"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:text="@string/dialer_two"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:text="@string/dialer_three"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: This didn't change my layout at all, the first and third columns are still larger than others due to more text.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the buttons were all different sizes because the default padding around my button text was too high.